# Neo4j python driver to connect to multiple database

Tags: python, neo4j, python-3.6

I have a Neo4j instance setup Neo4j 4.0 - Enterprise edition. I created a 2 database through UI

Docs on managing multiple databases here: https://neo4j.com/developer/manage-multiple-databases/

Databases:

1. system (this sytem database)
2. neo4j (default database)
3. Db1 (this is my newly created database 1)
4. Db2 (this is my newly created database 2)

Neo4j python official driver doesn't have the option to connect to the database (Db1, Db2)

Connection: GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://0.0.0.0:7687/", auth=('xx', "xx"), encrypted=False)

There is no parameter to mention what database to use. Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The driver is database-agnostic, and can access multiple databases via distinct sessions. `database=` is a `session` parameter. Example below for `Db1`:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://0.0.0.0:7687/", auth=('xx', "xx"), encrypted=False)
session = driver.session(database='Db1')
```

[Python Driver 4.0 Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#database)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not yet available in the python driver: https://twitter.com/technige/status/1230115017045008384?s=20